# Hide attachment record without code

Tags: administration, attachment, related-list, admin

Can someone please confirm if is there any way to hide sepecific records from notes and attachments records related to contacts, for example, I have 3 related attachments on contact object but I want to hide one of them from the user based on certain criteria.

As per the below screenshot the visibility is set to all user but I have no idea how to customize the same.

[image]

Thank you in anticipation!

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce out-of-box functionality doesn't allow to hide specific attachments from attachment related list of a Contact (or any other Parent object).

As there are no separate access rights or visibility can be provided for attachments. If user has access to Parent record then he/she has visibility to all the attachments of that Parent record.

Without customization, there are no other options.

Comment: Thank you so much for confirming